# str_replace magento product name

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

A quick one.

I've got a select input of magento simple products on a grouped product page.

I want to remove the grouped product name and leave the rest of the SKU.

e.g. simple product name: trfu00XS grouped product name: trfu00 result: XS

Have a look below.

```
<form>
<select id="tflitem" onchange="showSelected()" />

<option value="" selected>Size</option>

<?php if (count($_associatedProducts)): ?>
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>   

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
<option value="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?> <?php echo $_product->getName() ?>/ <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="tflIndex" size="5" />
QTY

</form>
```

Comment: side note.. if you want your code to speed up a little, write bigger blocks of PHP. opening/closing a block in PHP I believe it slows down the engine unless you are using some kind of optimizer and pre-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Some things:

SKU codes don't have to be minimum length possible, you can put dashes in them, e.g. TRFU-00-XS and you can use a consistent schema, e.g. BASE_SKU-SIZE-COLOR.

This makes it easier for people to work with, customers, order team, programmers. In this instance you can use PHP `strtok()` and other functions to get the component parts of the SKU.

I am not sure from your example what is a name and what is a SKU.

However, to get your base product SKU, before the foreach loop try `$basesku=$this->getSku();` or `$basename=$this->getName();`

Then you can `str_replace($basename,'',$_item->getName())` (or SKU) to get the bits on the end.

Comment: mmm...Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped::str_replace(Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => SR01002CS
)
)

Comment: str_replace as regular PHP - otherwise if that syntax is not working, save the $_item->getName() as something else in between. To be honest you could have been clearer on what you were using as names and sku's as that wasn;t clear to me.

Comment: in this case, the SKU is the name of the product too.